Getting this error Auth/Invalid API key error whenever I load my nextjs project even though firebase credientials are absolutely fine
⨯ FirebaseError: Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists with different options or config (app/duplicate-app).
at initializeApp (file:///C:/Users/mnmpa/Desktop/Projects/rce/node_modules/@firebase/app/dist/esm/index.esm2017.js:558:33)
at eval (webpack-internal:///./src/firebase/firebase.ts:24:132) {
code: 'app/duplicate-app',
customData: { appName: '[DEFAULT]' },
page: '/'
}
Sometimes I am getting this error while sometimes it shows auth/invalid api key error in my nextjs project
I tried everything mentioned on stack overflow as well as github solutions but none of them worked for me. Help me if anyone decode the problem here. Firebase is working fine in simple html login page but facing issue in this project only
